# Iterate through pandas dataframe to display specified columns on HTML for each row

Tags: python, html, web

I'm working on this html template where i want to fill in the values inside {{}} with values from a pandas dataframe. Each row is supposed to have its own template generated based on this template. How should I fix my code to display the values I want?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>"{{page_title}}"</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='styles.css') }}">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>"{{page_title}}"</h1>
        <img src = "/images/{{image_filename}}" alt = ""></img>
        <p>"{{description}}"</p>
    </body>
    </html>
```